# Fastest Way To Check Website Content Has Changed (Java Programming)

Tags: java, performance, https

There is a website which is fairly static in content throughout the day, but as soon as it is updated, we want to know it's been changed and we want to read the new content.  Every millisecond counts as there' a competitive advantage to reading this information first.

To do this, we use HttpsUrlConnection, and tell it not to use cache.  The reason for Https instead of Http is I've read the former is less likely to lead to content being cached.

```
String urlText = "https://somewebsite.com/1234.xml" + "?unused=" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
URL url = new URL(urlText);
HttpsURLConnection openConnection;
openConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
openConnection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
openConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
openConnection.setUseCaches(false);
```

We poll round and round on a loop, inspecting the content to check if any modification has been made.  The page content is 2k in size, so pretty small.

To further guard against any caching, we append a random argument of unused numbers to the end of the URL, to make the target server think it's a different request.  The random number changes each time.  The idea is as soon as the content is changed, we'll get a fresh version of the page and not some old version.

At the moment, the average time to check is around 110ms.  I am aware that using a VPS close to the target server would help but, aside from that, what else would improve the performance in a situation where every millisecond is vital?

1. Currently, we create a new openConnection every time round the loop, because we have a new URL every time (because of the random number argument which changes on every iteration).  However is this an extra overhead?  Could we somehow reuse the connection to cut down on SSL handshake, while still changing the URL to have a different unused argument?
2. Would starting multiple independent threads, each polling the same URL, help?  The first to notice the page has changed wins.  Better to have 10 threads checking, than just one.  Or is it...
3. Any other ideas?

Comment: Since this is intended to be a long running process, you don't need to use `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` each time you connect - just use a long and start off at 0 and increment by 1 each time. This would shave off about 10-12 ms.

Comment: I would also focus on the method you are using to check if the content has changed. How are you doing this now? Are there any shortcuts that can be used?

Comment: The non-network related processing takes average of 5ms each loop, so I really wanted to focus on the most efficient way of detecting an update to the content, without risking results being cached.